# Why AWS Glue job seems to use less executors sometimes into the job

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am trying to understand, why does my Glue job appears to not run on full parallelism most of the time?

[image]

As shown in the image, it seems like about halfway through the job, most executors stop? I am guessing some workloads are not really parallel? Can I understand which functions tend to cause this? Or is this expected?

When I check CloudWatch Logs, it seems like all I see is things like:

```
19/05/10 09:05:15 INFO Client: Application report for application_1557470405923_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/05/10 09:05:15 DEBUG Client: 
client token: N/A
diagnostics: N/A
ApplicationMaster host: 172.31.43.166
ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
queue: default
start time: 1557471194764
final status: UNDEFINED
tracking URL: http://ip-172-31-42-62.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:20888/proxy/application_1557470405923_0001/
user: root
19/05/10 09:05:16 INFO Client: Application report for application_1557470405923_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/05/10 09:05:16 DEBUG Client: 
client token: N/A
diagnostics: N/A
ApplicationMaster host: 172.31.43.166
ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
queue: default
start time: 1557471194764
final status: UNDEFINED
tracking URL: http://ip-172-31-42-62.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:20888/proxy/application_1557470405923_0001/
user: root
19/05/10 09:05:17 INFO Client: Application report for application_1557470405923_0001 (state: RUNNING)
19/05/10 09:05:17 DEBUG Client: 
client token: N/A
diagnostics: N/A
ApplicationMaster host: 172.31.43.166
ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
queue: default
start time: 1557471194764
final status: UNDEFINED
tracking URL: http://ip-172-31-42-62.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:20888/proxy/application_1557470405923_0001/
user: root
```

Seems like its still doing my quite large Spark SQL query ... because I do not see any logs indicating otherwise ... is there any way to understand what is Glue doing at various points? Eg. isit on this query or another for example?

Comment: I am using AWS Glue for the ETL and to my experience the logs are not much useful as it does not print the user logs or print statements till the end of the job. To mitigate this I started logging the progress in database which shows the step glue is executing to me at any point in time. Though not a direct way to find what is happening here, but this should give you some insight.